# htaccess redirect 301 and rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to simplify URLs from

xyz.com/walks/walk_descrip/8010/
to 
xyz.com/walk-8010

I have moved the file from the walks sub-directory to the root.

I have tried using the following in my htaccess file

```
Redirect 301 ^/walks/walk_descrip/(.*)/$ /walk-$1
RewriteRule ^walk-(.*)$ /walk-description.php?id=$
```

However this is producing URLs such as

```
xyz.com/walk-8010?id=8010
```

Where am I going wrong?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Redirect directive doesnt support regex. What you are looking for is RedirectMatch.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/walks/walk_descrip/(.+)$ /walk-$1
```

Comment: I have just tried this and it still produces the following example of an URL    www.xyz.com/walk-8009?id=8009 which is not waht I had expected